# Behavior of find() inside a for loop

Tags: python

I just started to learn python from scratch and I have a question related to the find() method.

This is a simplified version of an exercise that prints the index of a target in a string .

```
phrase = 'Here, there, everywhere!'
index = 0
target = 'ere'
for n in (0, 1, 2):
index = phrase.find(target, index + 1)
        print(index)

Output:
   1
   8
   20
```

I ran this step by step and although the result satisfies the exercise, I don't understand this part in particular `index = phrase.find(target, index + 1)` because if `index = 0` at the beginning and then inside the loop it gets `index + 1` why in the second cicle it becames `8` instead of `2`?

Comment: `find()` returns start index. Why should ever it return a 2 for your string?

Comment: English is not my first language so I sorry if i say something wrong, My point is that inside the parentheses index gets a +1, so isn't it supposed to be cumulative, like from 0, to 1, then 2... since the element after the comma specifies where to start

Comment: Your for-loop has three iterations. It iterates over three elements, 0 - 2 inclusive. For each iteration of the loop, the variable `n` takes on the current value. The first iteration, `n` will be `0`. The second iteration, `n` will be `1`. The third iteration, `n` will be `2`. However, you aren't actually using `n` anywhere. It has not effect or influence on `index = phrase.find(target, index+1)`, because you aren't actually using `n` for anything.

Comment: Your supposed `index` values are replaced by `find()` output, because you assign its output to same `index` variable.

Comment: Thanks, I think that answer the question

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this example to see how string.find works
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-find/

But to answer your question, 
1st iteration:

```
 ->phrase.find(target, index + 1) is looking for the string "ere" in the string "ere, there, everywhere!"
 ->it see that the first instance of "ere" occurs are index starting at 1
 ->phrase.find() thus returns 1
 ->index=1 now
```

2nd iteration:

```
 ->phrase.find(target, index + 1) is phrase.find(target, 2)

 ->Thus its looking for the string "ere" in the string "re, there, everywhere!"
 ->The 1st instance of "ere" can now be found starting at index 8
-> Thus you print out 8
```

and so on....

Comment: Thanks, my problem was that I didn't "see" that index was two times in one line